# What data access method does Stack Overflow use?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

What is the data access method used by the Stack Overflow family of sites?

Is it LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from [the FAQ, "What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with):

> **Data Access Layer** Linq to SQL